# DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException {"error":"consent_required"}" / Response Type Not Supported when attempting to grant consent

Tags: docusignapi

I tried to receive a token with the code below. Unfortunatelly I get the error:

```
DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Nachricht = Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code with response Body: {"error":"consent_required"}
```

I tried with set TLS 12 and without. We run it in dev mode with base path https://demo.docusign.net/restapi
and oAuthBasePath =account-d.docusign.com

I tried also to set the consens manually with the URL below. But I receive the error in (Login Window) invalid Authorization: RequestType is not supported.

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=a5ed47d5-xxxx-xxxx-8a19-756da64391de&redirect_uri=https://www.docusign.com
```

Is the something wrong with my account setting?

```
byte[] privateKey=DSHelper.ReadFileContent(DSHelper.PrepareFullPrivateKeyFilePath(privateKeyFilename));
            var scopes = new List<string>
                {
                    "signature",
                    "impersonation",
                };
            var basePath = ApiClient.Production_REST_BasePath;
            var oAuthBasePath = OAuth.Production_OAuth_BasePath;
            if (!production)
            {
                basePath = ApiClient.Demo_REST_BasePath;
                oAuthBasePath = OAuth.Demo_OAuth_BasePath;
            }

            
            var _apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            var authToken = _apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(
            clientId,
            ImpersonatedUserId,
            oAuthBasePath,
            privateKey,
            1,
            scopes);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. instead of reponse_type= `code` I have to use `token`

Answer (score 0):

What `response_type` is supported for an integration key depends on how the key is configured. In the *Authentication* section of the key's configuration panel, Auth Code Grant allows the response type of `code`, while Implicit Grant allows the response type of `token`.

DocuSign's authentication docs assume you have "Auth Code Grant" selected, but either is technically acceptable to allow JWT consent.

[image: Auth config panel]